# What is a 'hoisted manifest' in yarn

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

When trying to install a package with yarn I get the following error: `expected hoisted manifest for \"myPackage#@material-ui/core#react-dom\"`

But it isn't clear what a 'hoisted manifest' exactly is.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what it is.  Try deleting your `yarn.lock` file, and then run `yarn install`.

There is a bug raised with yarn:  https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7244